# Babel 6 doesn't transpile my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

This is my code

```
require('babel-register')
require('babel-polyfill')

const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

// logger

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  const start = new Date;
  await next();
  const ms = new Date - start;
  console.log(`${ctx.method} ${ctx.url} - ${ms}ms`);
});

// response

app.use(ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

An example taken by Koa v2.0 that use `async/await`. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

---

Here is the `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "koa": "^2.0.0-alpha.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.3.13",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

Comment: I bet you have to specify which presets / plugins to load. Have a look at the docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/ .

Comment: Already done... sorry I will show you my babelrc

Comment: So what is not clear to you? Your runtime does not know about arrow functions and you don't transpile them, hence it's a syntax error.

Comment: What is your run command? Do you use ```gulp``` or ```grunt``` that runs ```babel``` transformation task before running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. It needed to include `es2015` preset as well and move hook to another file